# how to communicate with openstack api using servlet

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, openstack

I am trying to write a sample program in order to communicate with OpenStack API. From the API documentation of OpenStack I found that with Java we need a REST client but couldn't write a single piece of code so can you provide me a sample piece of code to get token from OpenStack API?

Answer (score 3):

There are now (unofficial) [Java bindings for OpenStack](https://github.com/woorea/openstack-java-sdk).

Also, the [OpenStack API Quick Start](http://docs.openstack.org/api/quick-start/content/) has samples using curl about how to get an authentication token.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [OpenStack4j](http://openstack4j.com). It supports Keystone, Nova, Neutron, Glance and Cinder out of the box.  It's fast and fluent.